# Accelerate software running in linux

Tags: linux, testing

I need to test a software stability for one month under linux. Obviously, one month is too long . I am wondering, is there a tool that can accelerate this process, like if using this tool for 30 hours just like running this machine for one month (30 days)? Please be notice this tool should support linux. Thanks any reply in advance.

Li

Comment: Is the issue testing one for problems with particular date and times, or testing for bugs that would crop up after extend usage? If the latter, I'm not sure how such a tool could exist (it's effectively speeding up the computer for free...)

Comment: Not really sure why you would need to do this. If you're concerned about how a software product would handle 30 days, test it for 30 days. Don't skip ahead and introduce unnecessary variables and problems. If stability is a concern of yours, I recommend going the distance.

Comment: @David, the latter one. Sad to hear that.

Comment: @SevenBits, I am a quality assurance, and i need to make sure my software could running for one month without memory leak or crush issues. 30 days would be too long for one test cases, just image that we take 30 days for QA test, and the next 30 days for devs debugging and fixing, ang next 30 days for QA verify...

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this kind of testing is to estimate the workload, and to increase it.

Eg, heat and cool the system in extreme conditions, perhaps use a wind tunnel, or a heat source, whatever is needed to simulate "one month" of use.

On a more serious note, what kind of load are you expecting? Eg, will you have a person sit and use the program each day, and therefore need to worry about changing dates while the application is still in use?

Or will you expect 50,000 customers over the span of one month?

Comment: hi Arafangion, this is not a hardware , but software. Just image there is a server and needs to be running 24*7 without memory leak and other issues. The min requirements is server could run for 30 days, without disruption. However, manually setup an server machine and waiting 30 days makes this stupid. A tool that accelerate those process would be a better idea.

Comment: Hi DingLi, this might be software, but the same principles apply. Replicate the load you would expect to see in 30 days, and simulate that load faster.